# Selecting table of properties as columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab

I have two tables, `things` and `properties`:

```
CREATE TABLE things (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE properties (
  thing_id INT,
  key TEXT,
  value TEXT
);
```

I want to select from `things` and join rows from `properties` as columns. For example, say I have the following:

```
INSERT INTO things DEFAULT_VALUES;  -- suppose id is 1
INSERT INTO properties (thing_id, key, value) VALUES
  (1, 'height', '5'),
  (1, 'width', '6'),
  (1, 'length', '7');
```

How can I select from things with `height`, `width`, and `length` as columns?

Also, I don't want to *specifically* select `height`, `width`, and `length`, but any rows that may be inside properties.

Comment: Do you know what columns you want in the final result set?  If not, you need to do this using dynamic SQL.

Comment: Search for pivot, crosstab, dynamic SQL

Comment: A complete solution is not easy. For some cases a simpler solution is good enough. [Check one recent answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24813587/131874). If it interest you I can write it for your case.

Comment: Ah, welcome to EAV design.  Hopefully you sanitize inputs to `key` and `value`, or you'll get stuff like `key = 'Height'` (note capitalization), `key = 'hight'` (spelling), or `key = ' height'` (whitespace), and stuff like `key = 'height', value = 'five'`.  90+% of the time you can group/pivot rows into related tables (here, perhaps `Bounding_Box_Dimensions` or something) - most systems simply don't need the flexibility (because these are generally a pain to query/update safely).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For just three columns:

```
SELECT t.thing_id
      ,max(CASE WHEN p.key = 'height' THEN p.value END) AS height
      ,max(CASE WHEN p.key = 'width'  THEN p.value END) AS width
      ,max(CASE WHEN p.key = 'length' THEN p.value END) AS length
FROM   things t
LEFT   JOIN properties p ON p.thing_id = t.id
WHERE  t.id = 1
GROUP  BY 1;
```

Or use `crosstab()` from the additional module `tablefunc` which is typically faster, and shorter for long lists of attributes:

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
      'SELECT t.thing_id, p.key, p.value
       FROM   things t
       LEFT   JOIN properties p ON p.thing_id = t.id
       WHERE  t.id = 1
       ORDER  BY 1'

      ,$$VALUES ('height'::text), ('width'), ('length')$$) -- add more
AS ct (thing_id int, height int, width int, length int);   -- add more
```

Types have to match. Detailed explanation:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

A *completely* dynamic list of columns cannot be achieved in a single query. I have tried many times. Here is what *can* be done:

- [Dynamic alternative to pivot with CASE and GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506199/dynamic-alternative-to-pivot-with-case-and-group-by/15514334#15514334)

Comment: Did you mean to left join table THINGS with PROPERTIES (not properties w/ propertie)? Also he said that those are not the only 3 columns he wants.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and for the meta-answer that a completely dynamic list of columns is impossible. For those curious, I ended up using an [`hstore`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/hstore.html) instead.

Comment: Two things you might be interested in: [`jsonb` in the upcoming Postgres 9.4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24292575/how-to-query-a-json-column-for-empty-objects/24296054#24296054) and [this related question on dba.SE about EAV with detailed answers](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20759/is-there-a-name-for-this-database-structure).

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try table aliases here:

```
SELECT  p1.key, p2.key, p3.key
  FROM properties as t1
  JOIN properties AS p1 ON p1.thing_id= t1.thing_id
  JOIN properties AS p2 ON p2.thing_id= t1.thing_id
  JOIN properties AS p3 ON p3.thing_id= t1.thing_id
 WHERE t1.thing_id = 1;
```